# Is there a way to disown a site which uses my maps api v2 key?

Tags: google-maps

There is a site which uses my maps api v2 key and I get emails about the deprecation of v2. The site is abandoned and I have no control over it, so I can't remove my key from its code. Is there a way to indicate that that key does not belong to me anymore, so google should not associate me with it?

Comment: @danny117  well, a deprecation email is not that bad in itself, but one could also abuse my key, so there must be some way to disown keys over which I do not have control anymore, so they are not my responsibility

Comment: I imagine you can just shut the key off if your that worried.  Google API Console https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: it would be logical, the only problem is the key and the domain do not show up there, so I can't shut it off from there, yet it's still associated with my account, beacuse I keep getting emails about it